# How to read cookies of an application from a rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote a gem which will read the cookies of an application that installs my gem. But, I am not able to do that because when I try to add the line `cookies[:name]`, it is throwing the exception `undefined method "cookies"`.

How to achieve this? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You can only access `cookies` in the controller or view.  You need to add more info about your problem, eg where you are trying to access `cookies`.

Comment: I am trying to access the browser cookies from the gem

Comment: Cookies are only available when building a response or after receiving a request: ultimately you are just reading request headers and setting response headers. Outside of the context of the controller (which receives requests and makes responses), cookies are therefore not available.  If your gem has modules which are to be included in the controller then they may be able to access them.  But if it is effectively more "model" logic then it won't be able to access the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, applications don't store cookies, only browsers do. That said, you can access those cookies from your controllers. See the documentation on cookies here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies

Your question is kind of vague. You might have to share some code to get a quality answer.